# AngularJS достать из JSON значение

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Всем привет, я только начал учить AngularJS, поэтому не судите строго. У меня возник такой вопрос:
Мне с API приходит такой JSON:

```
{   
"isCar": true // false 
}
```

Есть сервис, который стучиться на АПИ и забирает то, что пришло:

```
function checkIfCar(carId) {
            $http.get(env.api + 'cars/iscar/' + carId).success(response => {
          return response.data.isCar; //так я хочу достать true или false
            }).error(function (data) {
                toastr.error('Something went wrong and we can\'t check:' + data);
            });
        }
```

Есть директива, из которой я вызываю этот метод:

```
function checkIfCar() {
                    var isCar = carService.checkIfCar(carId);

                    if (isCar === false) {
                        toastr.warning('This is not a car!');
                    }
                }
```

Когда я пытаюсь достать, то с АПИ всё хорошо приходит, а вот Ангуляр ругается

> Cannot read property 'isCar' of undefined

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вытянуть значение, которое пришло, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: вы в курсе что `$http.get` это асинхронный метод и как работать с промисами?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, я только знаю, что промисы нужны для получения ответа и последующего его преобразования. Может я конечно не правильно понимаю, но я всеми силами пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: в `success` уберите `return` и добавьте код `if (response.data.isCar === false) {
                        toastr.warning('This is not a car!');
                    }`

Comment: `response.data.isCar`, `Cannot read property 'isCar' of undefined` - лучче начать с распечатки response в консоль и внимательного осмотра его структуры. а уж потом промисы-нагетсы-сникерсы

Comment: @MrFylypenko, сделал, но результат тот же

Comment: как уже выше сказали, проверьте `response`, например выведите в консоль, посмотрите есть ли там `data.isCar` . Может там нужно использовать `response.isCar`